# Complex statement in MongoDB AND & OR conditions

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query

Continuing on my project, I need to translate some SQL statements to mongoDB

My SQL Statement is:

```
Delete from 'table' where proc_id = $xxx and (day_id < $day OR day_id > $anotherDay)
```

Now my condition array is this:

```
$condicion = array(
            'proc_id' => $xxx,
            '$or' => array(
                'day_id' => array(
                    '$lt' => $day,
                    '$gt' => $anotherDay

                    )
                )
            );
```

The function made for delete in mongo collections returns cannot delete...

Some help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each "day_id" would be in it's own [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) argument:

```
$query = array(
    'proc_id' = > $xxx,
    '$or' => array(
        array( 'day_id' => array ( '$lt' => $day ) ),
        array( 'day_id' => array ( '$gt' => $anotherDay ) ),
    )
)
```

That is how `$or` conditions work as a "list" of possible expressions.

The JSON syntax is clearer to visualise:

```
{
    "proc_id": $xxx,
    "$or": [
        { "day_id": { "$lt": $day } },
        { "day_id": { "$gt": $anotherDay }}
    ]
}
```

Since there is a very clear distinction between a "list" and an "object" definition. `$or` conditions are "lists" of "objects", and that means you list the full condition just as if it were a query in itself. Since this is not called within an `$elemMatch`.

And of course the "DELETE" part is the [**`.remove()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php) method:

```
$collection->remove($query)
```

There are general examples and resources in the core documentation [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/), where if the examples there do not immediately help, the linked articles and presentations should.